# Error showing "Include a platformName" capability

Tags: automated-testing, javascript, appium, mobile-automation

I recently started to learn Appium with Javascript.

When executing my script, I am getting an error stating "Include a platformName". I don't understand why, even though I have included it (platformName), it's still showing the error.

```
  Simple cases
1) "before all" hook

0 passing (250ms)
1 failing

1) Simple cases
   "before all" hook:
 Error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: You must include a platformName capability
  at new RuntimeError (node_modules\webdriverio\build\lib\utils\ErrorHandler.js:143:12)
  at Request._callback (node_modules\webdriverio\build\lib\utils\RequestHandler.js:318:39)
  at Request.self.callback (node_modules\request\request.js:185:22)
  at Request.<anonymous> (node_modules\request\request.js:1161:10)
  at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (node_modules\request\request.js:1083:12)
  at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
  at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
  at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:218:9)
```

Answer (score 1):

it seems to be an issue with the appium & selenium versions compatibility.

This error happens because you are using the selenium-java : v3.3.1 without the correct Appium java client

only from the latest appium java client 5.0.0-BETA7 it is possible to use selenium-java : v3.3.1.

or you can revert selenium-java back to 2.53.1

[refer this](https://github.com/appium/java-client)